# In java, How System.out.println method works in both static and non static context?

Tags: java, static, non-static, system.out

How `System.out.println` method works in both static and non static context?

Is there any JVM specific implementation is the answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

[`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is a static field / global object / singleton.

It is accessible everywhere, no need for a non-static context.

On that object (a `PrintStream` instance) you can call the `println` method.

Note that `PrintStream#println` is *not* a static method. But you can call non-static methods even from static methods as long as you have an instance to call them on (such as `System.out` here).

Static vs non-static context only makes a difference if you need access to `this` (the current instance of your own class). That is not needed here (unless you want to do `System.out.println(this)` -- that would not work from inside a static method).

None of this is "special" about `System.out` or requires internal JVM magic.

Comment: Actually  System class static block get initialized with registerNatives() .. And VM will invoke private initializeSystemClass() which calls a private native method setOut0(....native calls to c) which intializes PrintStream out to system depending output stream object.  Thanks 4 Ur answers.